# Check if two gps coordinates are in the same segment in Here.com js api

Tags: google-maps, here-api

I'm making an application that is uploading data from a gps device (the collection of points of where the vehicle has traveled). I'm having an issue when the vehicle stops or moves very slowly. The gps uploads repeated coordinates, which are unnecessary data.

Is there a way to check whether two (lat,lng) coordinates fall within the same road segment?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check by reverse geocoding and checking the reference-id in response 
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode

Or you can use Route Match Extension to try to get the correct route.
https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/route-match/topics/overview.html